# Can a reinforcement learning algorithm which may be implemented in some RL library for continuous spaces be used for discrete space by rounding off?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Can we use RL algorithms which are implemented for continuous action space for discrete action space environments by simply mapping (or rounding off) the agent's action in continuous space range (of the gym environment) to discrete actions in openai gym env?

Comment: i think statistically it'll be wrong approach. why not create a custom environment where the agent is trained on a discrete space?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works both ways, for an environment E with action space A_E you can just  define a wrapper W such that W(A) has an action space A_W of your choice, and it just translates the actions in between. Now is it the most efficient approach? Probably not, usually exploiting **any known structure of the problem** brings better results.